# Is it ok to use "at which" for places?

Tags: possessive-of-which, where-which

I want to ask that is using "at which" correct or not? For example, is the following sentence correct?

> In my opinion, ABCDEF is the place at which I can gain invaluable experiences.

Comment: By 'place' do you mean 'geographical location' or more broadly 'company / institution'?

Comment: I mean companies or institutions @EdwinAshworth

Answer (score -1):

Corrections-

I would like to ask whether using "at which", in the following context is correct or not.

In my opinion, ABCDEF is the place at which I can gain invaluable experience.

Answer: Yes, it is correct.  You could also say

In my opinion, ABCDEF is the place where I can gain invaluable experience.